# Running chromium in mc

Tags: mc, chrome

I cannot run chromium (71.0.3578.98 Built on Ubuntu, running on Ubuntu 18.04) in mc (GNU Midnight Commander 4.8.19). Specifically, in mc:

```
$ chromium-browser
[1:1:0117/041208.995908:FATAL:proc_util.cc(76)] : Bad file descriptor (9)
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

The problem persists even after rebooting in old mc and terminal windows (I have "Save session" set) and new mc windows but not new terminal windows. Any ideas? Can someone reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an obscure Chromium bug, and one that's probably a long time fixing. The bug occurs if you start `mc` w/ `bash -ic mc`, w/ `/usr/bin/mc` it works (I'm using a custom skin, one that I've got to work w/ `x-terminal-emulator -e bash -ic mc` only)